# How do I set the key in an each() function?

Tags: jquery, arrays, key, each

I am a beginner to jQuery and although it seems like an easy question I just don't seem to have the terminology to look it up on Google - have tried everything...

I am trying to do some Array parsing as a function and have put this thing together by looking it up on the web. I would like it to count the number of objects in an array where the "key" and "item" are the same. I already know that the key is wid and it is called via the key.

```
function countmeta(array, thekey, item) {
    var count = 0;
    var tkey = 'wid';
    $.each(array, function(i, v) { 
      if (v.thekey == item) 
        count++; 
    });
    return count;
}
```

If I set it manually it works perfectly:

```
$.each(array, function(i, v) { 
  if (v.wid == item) 
    count++; 
});
```

I also tried stuff like

```
var tkey = 'wid';
var tkey = "wid";
```

and

```
var tkey = thekey;
$.each(array, function(i, v) { 
  if (v.tkey == item) 
    count++; 
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I obviously have a gap in my understanding of what type of variable or string the `wid` represents in `v.wid`. Please help.

Comment: You need to use bracket notation when attempting to access the key of an object by variable. In this case `v[tkey]`. I would also suggest using the native `filter()` method and returning the length of the resulting array instead of using `$.each()`. It should be faster, doesn't rely on jQuery, and doesn't use an extra variable.

Comment: So simple. Thanks very much!